# Get full strings from `getstr` in ncurses in a non-blocking way

Tags: c, nonblocking, ncurses

What I am trying to do is have a chat window where text is continuously updated, and then an input window where a user can type in some message to add to the chat.

I am wondering if it is possible to use `getstr()` with nurses in such a fashion that `getstr()` will only return a string to me once I have hit the enter key.

This would allow me to continuously monitor the TCP connection for new messages, and then add a message to the chat once the user has entered his/her full message.

I have seen posts suggesting the user of `timeout()`, however this causes `getstr()` to return whatever the user has entered when the user has been inactive for some amount of time. This isn't really what I am looking for as in this case `getstr()` still blocks while the user is typing, and should a user stop to think about what they are writing half way through the message, that text is returned by `getstr()` before the user has confirmed this is the message he/she wants to send by pressing the enter key.

I am particularly curious about getting `getstr()` to work as then I don't have to manually handle delete/backspace/cursor movement operations manually. Given the scope of my project, it's a bit too large of an investment.

Comment: If you want to render other parts of the screen while the user is typing their input, it will necessitate moving the cursor, so this would always lead to possible races (if the user types while the renderer is still sending characters). For that reason, I'm afraid you're pretty much stuck with implementing your own handling of left/right/delete/backspace. But if you don't need to render anything, you could just use a second thread.

Comment: So I could use a second thread to grab input and pass the input along to the main program when necessary? This would allow the main program to keep rendering incoming messages?

Comment: No, ncurses can't be used from multiple threads (hence why threading is only an option if you don't need to render while waiting for input). Remember that ncurses just uses stdin and stdout to talk to the terminal, so no matter what, you're limited to a single cursor which must be used for both rendering and reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, I'm also working on something with a similar requirement (not a chat application though).

To reiterate what I said before: if you don't need to render anything, you could just use a second thread. Buf if you *do* need to render while waiting for input, you'll need to do the input handling yourself.

Why? because ncurses just talks to the terminal through `stdin` / `stdout`. That means you only get one cursor for handling both input and output, so if you move the cursor to print some output, the in-progress input will get messed up.

But it's not that hard to interpret & render the input yourself. Here's a reduced version of my first-pass solution:

```
// Compile with -lncurses

#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct input_line {
    char *ln;
    int length;
    int capacity;
    int cursor;
    int last_rendered;
};

void make_buffer(struct input_line *buf) {
    buf->ln = NULL;
    buf->length = 0;
    buf->capacity = 0;
    buf->cursor = 0;
    buf->last_rendered = 0;
}

void destroy_buffer(struct input_line *buf) {
    free(buf->ln);
    make_buffer(buf);
}

void render_line(struct input_line *buf) {
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < buf->length; i ++) {
        chtype c = buf->ln[i];
        if(i == buf->cursor) {
            c |= A_REVERSE;
        }
        addch(c);
    }
    if(buf->cursor == buf->length) {
        addch(' ' | A_REVERSE);
        i ++;
    }
    int rendered = i;
    // Erase previously rendered characters
    for(; i < buf->last_rendered; i ++) {
        addch(' '); 
    }
    buf->last_rendered = rendered;
}

int retrieve_content(struct input_line *buf, char *target, int max_len) {
    int len = buf->length < (max_len - 1) ? buf->length : (max_len - 1);
    memcpy(target, buf->ln, len);
    target[len] = '\0';
    buf->cursor = 0;
    buf->length = 0;
    return len + 1;
}

void add_char(struct input_line *buf, char ch) {
    // Ensure enough space for new character
    if(buf->length == buf->capacity) {
        int ncap = buf->capacity + 128;
        char *nln = (char*) realloc(buf->ln, ncap);
        if(!nln) {
            // Out of memory!
            return;
        }
        buf->ln = nln;
        buf->capacity = ncap;
    }

    // Add new character
    memmove(
        &buf->ln[buf->cursor+1],
        &buf->ln[buf->cursor],
        buf->length - buf->cursor
    );
    buf->ln[buf->cursor] = ch;
    ++ buf->cursor;
    ++ buf->length;
}

int handle_input(struct input_line *buf, char *target, int max_len, int key) {
    if(!(key & KEY_CODE_YES) && isprint(key)) {
        add_char(buf, key);
        return 0;
    }

    switch(key) {
    case ERR: /* no key pressed */ break;
    case KEY_LEFT:  if(buf->cursor > 0)           { buf->cursor --; } break;
    case KEY_RIGHT: if(buf->cursor < buf->length) { buf->cursor ++; } break;
    case KEY_HOME:  buf->cursor = 0;           break;
    case KEY_END:   buf->cursor = buf->length; break;
    case '\t':
        add_char(buf, '\t');
        break;
    case KEY_BACKSPACE:
    case 127:
    case 8:
        if(buf->cursor <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        buf->cursor --;
        // Fall-through
    case KEY_DC:
        if(buf->cursor < buf->length) {
            memmove(
                &buf->ln[buf->cursor],
                &buf->ln[buf->cursor+1],
                buf->length - buf->cursor - 1
            );
            buf->length --;
        }
        break;
    case KEY_ENTER:
    case '\r':
    case '\n':
        return retrieve_content(buf, target, max_len);
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_line_non_blocking(struct input_line *buf, char *target, int max_len) {
    while(1) {
        int key = getch();
        if(key == ERR) {
            // No more input
            return 0;
        }
        int n = handle_input(buf, target, max_len, key);
        if(n) {
            return n;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    initscr();

    cbreak();             // Immediate key input
    nonl();               // Get return key
    timeout(0);           // Non-blocking input
    keypad(stdscr, 1);    // Fix keypad
    noecho();             // No automatic printing
    curs_set(0);          // Hide real cursor
    intrflush(stdscr, 0); // Avoid potential graphical issues
    leaveok(stdscr, 1);   // Don't care where cursor is left

    struct input_line lnbuffer;
    make_buffer(&lnbuffer);

    int lines_read = 0;
    while(1) {
        char ln[1024];
        int len = get_line_non_blocking(&lnbuffer, ln, sizeof(ln));
        if(len > 0) {
            if(strcmp(ln, "exit") == 0) {
                break;
            }
            mvaddstr(7 + lines_read, 5, ln);
            lines_read ++;
        }
        move(5, 5);
        render_line(&lnbuffer);

        // Show that we are active
        mvaddch(2, 2, '0' + (rand() % 10));
        // (probably a good idea to sleep here)
    }

    destroy_buffer(&lnbuffer);
    delwin(stdscr);
    endwin();
    refresh();

    return 0;
}
```

There are plenty of control characters which haven't been implemented there (most notably INSERT), but it should be quite straightforward to add anything you think is important to your particular application. Also note that if you want unicode (recommended) you'll need to use ncursesw and its alternative functions.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I had to do a bit of modification to get it work with unicode, but it wasn't much a problem at all. Thank you very much!